# Pin folder to Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-3, project-management

I have windows 7 and am trying to pin my projects folder to sublime text so that I can right click it in the taskbar and open up the folder. I have tried pinning the folder itself, a shortcut to the folder and a batch file which opens the folder (that opened the batch file in sublime text and did not run it).

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to switch projects quickly; does the hotkey `CTRL + ALT + P` not switch projects fast enough for you?

Otherwise there's no way to pin a folder to `subl3` and have it open in `explorer.exe`. You'll have to pin it to the `explorer` icon on the taskbar.

Or is there another reason you want to quickly open the projects folder?

Comment: I want to open the folder in windows explorer. I've always liked that more that file navigating within sublime text.

Comment: There's no way to pin a folder to `subl3` and have it open in `explorer.exe`. You'll have to pin it to the `explorer` icon on the taskbar.

Comment: Thats pretty stupid of windows.

Comment: @Marcel It's a super strange workflow to want to pin a folder to one program, but then have it open with a different program. So It's not really that windows is stupid; more of a they don't support chain loading different programs because it's a security risk.